# Oauth2 authentication using Jhipster's gateway and UAA without cookies

Tags: cookies, oauth-2.0, microservices, jhipster

I am testing Jhipster to create microservices and I have some doubts about authentication using OAuth2, I created the project for the gateway and the UAA project and when testing the authentication part I noticed that authorization, update and CSRF tokens are always on cookies, I wonder if there is a way to remove this data from cookies, getting only in the header?

If I remove this information from the cookie, I will not need CSRF any more, right?

How do I get a new token using the refresh_token without cookies?

I tried some gateway addresses but I could not, I was only able to access the UAA but I do not think this is ideal!

Does anyone know where it has any documentation showing how is the oauth authentication stream using Gateway and UAA?